# Change value of input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple `input`'s which have different `data-id`'s.

If the input is clicked, I want to change the value of that input. I tried this but it didn't work, I've searched but couldn't find a solution.

```
<script>
$('[data-id]').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-id').parent().value("changed value successfully!");
  //I tried this one below as well
  //$(this).attr('data-id').parent().input.value("changed value successfully!");
});
</script>
```

```
<div>
   <input type="submit" data-id="1" value="hello world">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="submit" data-id="2" value="hello world">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="submit" data-id="3" value="hello world">
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: typo — the method is called `val()` not `value()`. You should have got an error telling you that `value()` was not a function.

Comment: When referring to AJAX you actually mean jQuery. You might find help easier online when googling JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/j4bu6923/3/

```js
$('input[data-id]').click(function() {
   $(this).val("changed value successfully!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <input type="text" data-id="1" value="hello world">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" data-id="2" value="hello world">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" data-id="3" value="hello world">
</div>
```

Comment: Added an edit for an embedded code snippet if you don't mind.